# List of major JavaScript frameworks/libraries

Tags: javascript

I'm beginning to dig a little deeper into JavaScript development and would like to cut time off discovering what tools do I have to use to do the job. I'm looking for some website where all major JavaScript libraries and frameworks would be listed by the category.

Is there anything like *[www.ruby-toolbox.com](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com)* in the JavaScript world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there anything like [www.ruby-toolbox.com](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com) in the JavaScript world?

There is not. I tried googling around a bit, and here are some that come close:

- http://www.javascriptplugins.com/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide
- http://microjs.com/

Also see
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs*.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is the most complete catalog for JavaScript libraries sorted in categories.

http://jster.net/

Answer (score 3):

A recent addition, and by far the most comprehensive of the ones suggested, is JSDB:

http://www.jsdb.io/

Answer (score 2):

There are too many libraries available to list them all. If you need a script for a specific purpose, google for that. However, I found some lists on the web:

- [microjs.com](http://microjs.com/) - compact-but-powerful microframeworks
- [github.com/Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) - HTML5 [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming))
- [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) - "notable" JavaScript libraries and frameworks

You may also find the big frameworks when looking around at the major content delivery networks, like [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide), [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) or (for smaller ones) [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tangential, but devdocs.io an excellent place to look for documentation on many of the major JavaScript frameworks.

http://devdocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

The resources available are likely highly subjective. However, you can consult **[Comparison of JavaScript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)** found on Wikipedia.

> There are many JavaScript frameworks available. The intention of this
> comparison is to show some examples of JavaScript frameworks with
> their different features.

You can also find a list of notable libraries in the [List of JavaScript libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) article. However, a comparison is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You must take at look at this amazing page: [The Toolbox](http://www.thetoolbox.cc/)

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. This looks more like a list of services than libraries, but it looks useful so thanks for the tip! Hope there will be added more projects in the future.

Comment: @Sergey btw, if it's of your interest, subscribe to this list http://javascriptweekly.com/ and get updated weekly about this fantastic JS world!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer, but a usable alternative: http://search.npmjs.org/ - I can just enter a keyword and it will list projects for that specific need. Although it doesn't show which tools are most used and trusted, it's the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yup. It works with node.js packages. Interesting.