# Cannot find equivalent of ruby-toolbox for javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, ruby, npm

I am looking for a website that is similar to [ruby-toolbox.com](http://ruby-toolbox.com) but after much effort I can't be able to find one.

Do you have any recommendation to an up-to-date and well maintained JS libraries registry?

Comment: http://npmjs.org is good, but there's a LOT of stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of major javascript frameworks/libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422888/list-of-major-javascript-frameworks-libraries)

Comment: I found something on github if it's helpful, https://github.com/blackwatertepes/js-toolbox

Answer (score 1):

I would appreciate as well learning what the NPM community is favoring for module comparisons.

I think the original poster was looking for something like the side by side comparison tools of ruby-toolbox.  npmjs has data points like download statistics, repository update dates and issues in github per package on, but not a side by side comparison.  I found the rating system on https://npmcompare.com to be more similar to rubytool-box.

Even though I find the side by side analysis helpful, it's worth noting that it's good for a developer to become skilled with how to assess for themselves modules for any platform. Here are some of the questions to ask.

1. Is the project active and current?
2. Is it popular?
3. Does the project have a good amount of dependencies for your needs?
4. Can you get visibility into it's code climate?
5. Are there tests?
6. Are issues responded too?

Comment: @dcohenb you're right I was mistaken. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend https://js.libhunt.com & https://nodejs.libhunt.com . Both sites have well categorized projects that are ordered by popularity in Github and their development activity. Moreover, you can compare different libs.

I hope this helps!